# javascript different html pages show different datepickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, datepicker

I need to show the same datepicker interface and style in all of the places I use datepickers.

The first page shows the datepicker like this: Here img 1and img 2 are in two different html pages.

[image: img 1]
[image: img 2]

img 1:

```
<input  name="start" id="datepicker1" type="text" value="<?php echo(set_value('start') ? set_value('start') : date("y-m-d")); ?>"  class="form-control">
<input  name="end" id="datepicker2" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('end'); ?>"  class="form-control">

  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
  });
```

img 2:

```
<input  name="start" id="datepicker3" type="text" value="<?php echo ((!set_value('start')) ? $offerinfo->startdate : set_value('start')); ?>"  class="form-control datepicker">
<input  name="end" id="datepicker4" type="text" value="<?php echo ((!set_value('end')) ? $offerinfo->enddate : set_value('end')); ?>"  class="form-control datepicker">

$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker3" ).datepicker();
    $( "#datepicker4" ).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: You might have missed the date picker css in the second date picker.

Comment: Or perhaps you have different styles that overlap the date picker on each page?

Comment: they look like 2 different datepickers - the second one seems to be the _jQuery UI Datepicker_ and the first one  i don't know maybe one of the bootstrap derivatives...

Comment: @sintakonte      thanks a lot. my problem was solved. I used: <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/admin/plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script> above the second one and it worked. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using 2 different datepickers - the first one was a bootstrap datepicker and the other datepicker was something else.

Changing both into bootstrap datepickers gave the same style and interface in both datepickers.

I added the following link above the second one as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/admin/plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker3" ).datepicker();
    $( "#datepicker4" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what datepicker you're using, you could try to set the `dateformat` option.

Example:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    });

    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    });

    $( "#datepicker3" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    });

    $( "#datepicker4" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the configuration

```
$('.datepicker3').datepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
});
```

Comment: there is no change in the datepicker interface yet.